# Is there a practical reason why LINQ's LongCount extension method was added?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, ienumerable, linq-to-objects

LINQ has 2 methods for counting enumerables: `Count` and `LongCount`. Practically the only difference between these two is that the first returns an `int`, while the second returns a `long`.

I'm unclear as to why the second method was added. It seems its only use case would be to handle enumerables of over 2B elements. This seems like a poor decision to me, for a few reasons:

1. Most BCL collections are backed by single-dimensional arrays, which have lengths that are guaranteed to fit in an `int`. Trying to go past that will raise an `OverflowException` / `OutOfMemoryException`.
2. `LongCount` is O(n) since `IEnumerable` is lazy. If you have a 3B element enumerable, you call `LongCount` on it, and then you iterate through it again (which you will have to if you want to use any of the values), you will be adding an extra 3B iterations, which will be extremely slow, and hiding it from the developer.
3. Other LINQ operations, such as `ToArray` / `ToList`, do not support enumerables with 2B+ elements because of (1).

Am I missing something here, or is there a more practical reason why `LongCount` was added? Thanks.

Comment: Based on source code `LongCount` just iterates through `IEnumerable` by `Enumerator.MoveNext`, while `Count` trying cast `IEnumerable` to the `ICollection` and use it's `Count` if casting was unsuccesful it will iterate `IEnumerable` in same way as `LongCount`. [https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,d76b4b5d3fd67767](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,d76b4b5d3fd67767). Based on this "guess" by @EricLipert seems very logical

Comment: @Fabio, that's just an optimization. It would be semantically correct for `LongCount` to check for `ICollection` too and just cast the result to `long`, but `LongCount` is not used as much, so that's why they haven't bothered doing that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have no first-hand knowledge of this design decision but I can offer an educated guess.

The method is of obvious usefulness for `IQueryable`; the query could easily be backed by an enormous database table.

I would expect

```
IQueryable<Foo> q = whatever;
long result1 = q.LongCount();
long result2 = q.AsEnumerable().LongCount();
```

to produce the same answer. It seems perverse to require in-memory queries to use a different method that returns a different type, particularly when it is so easy to implement the enumerable version.

But like I said, that's an educated guess; hopefully someone who actually worked on this design might chime in.

Comment: Yesterday I was going to answer something like this until I reached the `LongCount` implementation in `Enumerable.cs`. It simply enumerates the sequence from the start to the end. I thought I was going to find something like checking if the `IEnumerable<T>` implementation was `ICollection<T>` and play with `Count` or who knows what.

Comment: Even if we would be talking about some kind of enumerable backed by a network stream, at the end of the day, `LongCount` would go one by one to check that *long count*.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer: That is incorrect.  To expand on Eric Lippert's example of an enormous database table: Querying a count on a database very frequently avoids going one by one, instead relying on indexes and metadata to compute the count in sublinear time.  A less database-oriented example would be a sorted random access list containing duplicates.  One could acquire the count in O(logn) time by running a slightly modified binary search.  A database can perform similar optimizations based on indexes.

Comment: @Brian I said that because I checked `Enumerable.LongCount` source code, and it just does a `while` loop to accumulate the number of items in a given sequence :\

Comment: You are both correct. The LINQ-to-objects implementation just does a simple enumeration and count, unlike `Count` which checks to see if the count is already known. The LINQ-to-SQL implementation remotes the count operation over to the database.

Comment: What is missing is an understanding that an expression in C# may be the input into a separate run time compiler that does not make use of the implementation of any methods the expression “calls”.  IQueryable is often the wapper round such a compiler, .e.g LINQ-to-SQL.   (Mostly history as Microsoft did not open source LINQ-to-SQL before it was too late.)

Comment: "I would expect … to produce the same answer". You might also expect `someEnumerable().AsQueryable().LongCount()` to not throw at runtime, which it would if `Enumerable.LongCount` didn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

I'm quite sure it was introduced for database queries (for example it should generate COUNT_BIG instead of COUNT for sql server queries), however it *might* have some use in another situations. For example suppose I have such method:

```
private static Random _r = new Random(1);
public static IEnumerable<BigInteger> RandomSequence(int upTo)
{
    while (true) {
        var next = _r.Next();
        if (next > upTo)
            yield break;
        yield return next;
    }
}
```

This sequence is not baked by any array and does not store values anywhere. As such, it can easily produce more than 2B items. Now suppose I want to check, how many iterations it would take to generate number bigger than `int.MaxValue - 5`. If I do this:

```
RandomSequence(int.MaxValue - 5).Count();
```

It will fail with overflow exception (because `Count` conveniently internally wraps increment in `checked` region). But `LongCount` to the rescue!

```
RandomSequence(int.MaxValue - 5).LongCount();
```

Now I finally figured out that with seed 1, `Random.Next` will produce result bigger than `int.MaxValue - 5` in 2583066202 iterations!

Yes, example is somewhat contrieved, but still.